# Getting the X/Y coordinates of the "current cell" in a DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

[using VB 2010 / Winforms]

I have a DataGridView with several columns. It's unbound, and not connected to any sort of database or anything -- I am simply populating it cell by cell based on user input.

So anyways, one of the columns in the DGV is of type "image" (DataGridViewImageColumn).

What I'm trying to do is whenever one of the image cells is clicked, a context menu strip is shown at the exact loaction where the image cell is clicked.

Here's what I've got so far...

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick

        Dim columnName As String = DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name
        If columnName = "Image" Then 
         Me.Status_ContextMenuStrip1.Show(Me.DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ContentBounds.Location) ' <-- This isn't right, but I must be close!
        End If

End Sub
```

When I run the above code and click on an image cell, the context menu appears, but it appears at the very top left corner of the screen. How can I get it to appear at the exact location that the clicked cell is at? I'd actually like it to appear just below the clicked cell, so that it has a similar visual effect to a combobox "drop down" (and I know how to offset the X and Y coordinates as soon as I can figure out how to get it in the general vicinity of where it needs to be).

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Try the following code

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    Dim columnName As String = DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name

    If columnName = "Image" Then
        Dim RowHeight1 As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Height
        Dim CellRectangle1 As Rectangle = DataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, False)

        CellRectangle1.X += DataGridView1.Left
        CellRectangle1.Y += DataGridView1.Top + RowHeight1

        Dim DisplayPoint1 As Point = PointToScreen(New Point(CellRectangle1.X, CellRectangle1.Y))

        ContextMenuStrip1.Show(DisplayPoint1)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks David... I appreciate you taking the time out to post all that! Just tested your code, and that's "in the neighborhood" of the correct location, so I could offset it if that was the only problem. But unfortunately, the bigger problem is that it moves around when the GUI is resized. I did a little more online research though and figured out a good workaround, after a little bit of tweaking. In case anyone is interested, it's ShaneO's answer at this link --> http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/598859-how-get-currentcell-location-datagridview

Comment: The GetCellDisplayRectangle method returns a rectangle which has a location relative to its container. In this example, its container is just the Form.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone struggling with this in future - this is what really works:

```
'For forms
Dim f as New Form2
f.Location = DGV.PointToScreen(DGV.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, False).Location)
```

For case of this post:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As
  Dim DisplayPoint1 As Point = DGV.PointToScreen(DGV.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, False).Location)
ContextMenuStrip1.Show(DisplayPoint1)
End Sub
```

Comment: I had a similar problem and found the code above to be a solution to display the ContextMenuStrip at the top left corner of a cell, always. Given that the Y position was correct, but not the X, I kept the X position from the event arguments. So using: contextMenuStrip1.Show(new Point(e.X, DisplayPoint1.Y)) worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code like this ..

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick

    Dim columnName As String = DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name
    If columnName = "Image" Then 
       DataGridView1.CurrentCell = dgvDataDaftar.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex)
       Me.Status_ContextMenuStrip1.Show(dgvDataDaftar, DataGridView1.PointToClient(Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position))
    End If

End Sub
```